# 1D array decays to pointer, but 2D array doesn't do so, why?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Can someone explain to me why technically a 2D array does not actually decay to `int**` whereas when you have a single dimensional array, you do get pointer decay to `int*` (if you had array of `int`).

I understand what pointer decay is, but I don't get why the 2D array doesn't exhibit this decay?

It's a common confusion with people new to C or C++, but I find myself tripping over it often too.

Comment: Well, it decays to a pointer to an array. I guess it's defined not to screw up your iteration by changing the size of each element.

Comment: There's no such thing as a 2D array in C (or C++), there are only arrays of arrays. Once you've discarded this misconception, your question is much simpler to answer.

Comment: You can always cast the array to `(int *)` if you want to discard the dimensions.

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810676/252000) useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have different memory layouts.  A 2D array is one contiguous piece of memory while `int**` is an array of pointers.  With a 2D array, the offset into a location is computed as `rownum * collength + colnum` (or vice versa depending on how you label rows/columns).  That would not work with `int**`, which actually produces two memory reads; the first to get the column pointer, then the read of the data at an offset from that memory.

This different layout is, incidentally, why you must declare the array dimensions (all but the left-most) in functions that accept 2D arrays; otherwise it would not be possible for the compiler to generate the code to compute the offsets.

The following is an attempt at a picture of the memory layout of `int**`.  The left column is a contiguous array of pointers where each contains the address of a contiguous piece of memory with the data.  Note that the data in each column does not have to be the same length (although that might not necessarily be a good thing for code readability):

```
int **array; 
int i, j;
int cntr = 1;
array = malloc( 3 * sizeof( int* ));
for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
   array[i] = malloc( 4 * sizeof( int ));
   for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
      array[i][j] = cntr++;
   }
```

Gives something like this:

```
array ==> |addr1|  ==>  [1,2,3,4]
          |addr2|  ==>  [5,6,7,8]
          |addr3|  ==>  [9,10,11,12]
```

In contrast, This is what the layout might look like for `int[3][4]`.  The brackets just show the logical break of each column of data.  The integer values are contiguous in memory:

```
int array[3][4];
int i, j;
int cntr = 1;
for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
   for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
      array[i][j] = cntr++;
```

Gives something like this:

```
array ==> [1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][9,10,11,12]
```

Comment: So an array of pointers is not necessarily contiguous?

Comment: Not generally, although it could be allocated as a single chunk and then partitioned into arrays of pointers within the chunk.  But the offset computations would still be completely different.

Comment: care to give me an example for the pointer to pointer computation?

Comment: @TonyTheLion:  Are you asking about the assembly instructions that are produced?

Comment: @TonyTheLion - the pointers in an array of pointers are contiguous (as are the elements in an array of any type of object). That's why the second decay doesn't happen: an array of objects is not an array of pointers to objects, even when the type of the objects is an array.

Comment: @MarkWilkins I'm asking about the calculation to compute offsets for pointer to pointers vs double arrays, so I can see the differences.

Comment: @TonyTheLion:  There isn't a single computation.  It requires two memory accesses, which I tried to explain in the answer.  I'll see if I can clarify it.

Answer (score 4):

The pattern is that an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`".  If `T` is an array type, then you wind up with a pointer to an array.  Given a declaration like

```
T arr[M][N];
```

the expression `arr` has type "M-element array of N-element arrays of `T`".  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, it will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to N-element array of `T`", or `T (*)[N]`.

When in doubt, write out the type in English, such as "four-element array of five-element arrays of six-element arrays of `int`", then replace the first "n-element array of" with "pointer to", giving "pointer to 5-element arrays of 6-element arrays of `int`":

```
Declaration                Expression          Type              Decays to
-----------                ----------          ----              ---------
int arr[4][5][6];                 arr          int [4][5][6]     int (*)[5][6]
                               arr[i]          int [5][6]        int (*)[6]
                            arr[i][j]          int [6]           int *
                                 &arr          int (*)[4][5][6]  n/a
```

Comment: Excellent technical answer.

Answer (score 3):

The result of converting a two-dimensional array to a pointer to its first element is a pointer, not an array. Since it is not an array, it is not converted further.

Comment: Correct answer, but for more context you could add the information of the pointer type resulting from the decay of a 2-D array.

Comment: Correct answer, but for more context you could add the information of the pointer type resulting from the decay of a 2-D array.

Answer (score 2):

It does decay. An expression whose type is "array of T" decays into a pointer to its first element. For a 2-dimensional array of `T`, the first element has type array of `T`. So:

```
int arr[5];
```

In most contexts, `arr` has type "pointer to `int`". Now apply the **same** rule to a 2-dimensional array:

```
int arr2[5][5];
```

Here, `arr2` has type "pointer to array of 5 `int`". Note that the type of this object is **not** "array of `T`", so it does not decay further.

Comment: I believe `arr2` would be "pointer to array of 6 int" not 5.

Comment: @Kludas - you're probably right. I **always** have to look up which is which. It's not relevant here, so I've changed it to use the same size for both dimensions, rather than deal with it properly. `<g>`.

Comment: Wait? you say it does decay at first, but then say it doesn't decay further at the end.  I'm confused...

Comment: @TonyTheLion - I may have confused things by replying to the words in the title rather than the question itself. The top-level array part decays; the lower-level does not. So `int arr2[5][5]` decays into a pointer to array; the resulting type is **not** an array, it's a pointer, so it does not decay further.

Answer (score 1):

It is common mistake that one might think that if `int*  i` == `int i[5]` than `int** i` == `int i[5][5]` but it is not like that that for two reasons. First an `int**` is a [pointer to a pointer](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html) and has nothing to do with the ways arrays are laid out and secondly a 2D array is actually 1D array internally and what it does is lay the second arrays side by side.

That means that in an array of `[2][2]` internally is creating an array of `[4]` and when you try and access `[0][0]` than that gets translated to `[0]`, `[0][1]` will get translated to `[1]`, `[1][0]` will get translated to `[2]` and `[1][1]` will get translated to `[3]`

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

void Print(int* i, int element)
{
    std::cout << i[element] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i[5][5];

    i[2][2] = 125;

    Print((i[0]), 12);
}
```

This will print 125 because I set `[2][2]` as 125 and that will be consider as equal to `12` because the first `[0]` will occupy from 0 - 4, `[1]` will occupy from 5-10 and so on and so forth.

Comment: Irrelevant implementation details are not the way to explain language semantics.

Comment: This doesn’t actually explain why it cannot be converted to an `int**`.

Answer (score 1):

A two-dimensional array is an array *of arrays*.

An "array of `T`" is - in most contexts - converted to a "pointer to `T`, so an "array of `T[N]`" is converted to a "pointer to `T[N]`".

Since the memory representation of an

```
int arr[M][N];
```

is completely different from

```
int **dptr = malloc(M*sizeof *dptr);
for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    dptr[i] = malloc(N*sizeof *dptr[i]);
```

an `int[M][N]` cannot even be converted to an `int**`.

Answer (score -1):

A 2D array is a contiguous block of memory. When accessing it as a 2D array you need row length to jump from column to column. A pointer to a pointer is exactly that. It can simulate a 2D array if the first pointer is an array of pointers to a second dimension of arrays but it is a very different beast to the contiguous block of memory that a 2D array is.